# How to find limit of sequence $a_1=1$, $a_{n+1}=\left( 1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} \right)a_n$ for $n\geq 1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I need some help finding this limit.

> Define a sequence by $a_1=1$ and
>   $a_{n+1}=\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)a_n$ for $n\geq1$. Show that the limit exists and find the limit.

I've shown that the limit $L$ exists by showing it's decreasing and bounded below by $0$, but I'm not sure how to actually find it. I couldn't get a general formula for $a_n$. Also, the trick where I write $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}$ and substitute the formula for $a_{n+1}$ doesn't seem to work here.

I calculated the first few terms and it seems like $L$ is $1/2$, but otherwise I'm stuck here and not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1-\frac 1{k^2} = \frac{(k-1)(k+1)}{k^2}$, so the product is
$$
\frac{(2-1)(2+1)}{2\cdot 2}\cdot\frac{(3-1)(3+1)}{3\cdot 3}\cdot\frac{(4-1)(4+1)}{4\cdot 4}\cdot\frac{(5-1)(5+1)}{5\cdot 5}\cdot\dots
$$
i.e.,
$$
\frac{3}{2\cdot 2}\cdot\frac{2\cdot 4}{3\cdot 3}\cdot\frac{3\cdot 5}{4\cdot 4}\cdot\frac{4\cdot 6}{5\cdot 5}\cdot\dots
$$
Do you see something?

Comment: Oooooh so in $a_n$ all the terms cancel except the first 2 in the denominator and the final $(n+1)/n$. I think my mistake was simplifying too early so I couldn't see the pattern. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure. If you are content with my answer, please check it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It follows immediately from the definition of $a_{n+1}$ that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$ (and by induction, $a_n>0$ for all $n$), so that $a_n$ is decreasing. So $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\inf_n a_n$ exists. Using the hint in @amsmath's answer, we find that $a_n = \frac{n+1}{2n}$. This is clear for $n=1$, and if it is true for some $n\geqslant 1$ then
\begin{align}
a_{n+1} &= \left(1 - \frac1{(n+1)^2}\right)a_n\\&= \left(1 - \frac1{(n+1)^2}\right)\cdot\frac{n+1}{2n}\\
&= \frac{n+2}{2n+2}\\
&= \frac{(n+1)+1}{2(n+1)},
\end{align}
so by induction the formula holds. Hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{2n}=\frac12.$$